# Insert documents in Mongo without ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The below code snippet inserts a JSON object from a POST request. The problem is it also prefixes the string ***ObjectId*** with every unique key. Please see expected and current output for more clarity.

```
 module.exports.addMethod = function (db, req) {

  var body = "";
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });

  req.on('end', function () {
      var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);   

    db.collection("someCollection").insert(jsonBody, function(err,data) {
        if(err){
            console.log("cannot addd shit");
        }// error handling
          console.log("added your stuff");  
      });
  })// req.on ends here
}// addMethod ends here
```

Expected output:

[image]

Current Output:

[image]

I want to get rid of the **ObjectId** that is being prefixed with every unique id. I've tried `stringifying` it but of no use.

NOTE: I'm not using `expressjs` therefore my assumption is I can't use `body-parser`. I don't want to use expressjs.

Comment: You are including the same picture twice. Replacing them with text is a good idea as it makes them searchable and the question easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongodb will automatically generate the ['_id'](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#id-field) field only if you do not specify a value for the `_id` field when you insert a document. So you can just manually set the `_id` when you insert the document:

```
jsonBody._id = "123"; // for example
db.collection("someCollection").insert(jsonBody, function(err,data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [by design](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/):

> **_id Field**
>
> If the document does not specify an _id field, then MongoDB will add the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document before inserting. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the _id field, but the mongod will create and populate the _id if the driver or application does not.

You *need* a primary key.